# How many databases does a sybase instance have?

Tags: database-design, sybase-ase, sap

I'm a newbie to sybase and could not find the clear answers on Sybase tutorials/docs

- How many databases can one Sybase instance have? Oracle has one
  instance which corresponds to only one database, is it the same with
  Sybase ?
- What is a master database, is it a db that holds metadata? Does each
  instance have one master database ?
- What is a user database ? Is it similar to a tenant db in sap hana ?

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS are you referring to? (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?)

Comment: I'm referring to ASE

Answer (score 2):

ASE can have up to 32K dbs (includes various system dbs).

The `master` db holds server wide metadata (eg, logins, roles, configs, databases) and can also hold user data (though this is discouraged).

Other system databases include `sybsystemprocs` (collection of system stored procs and functions), `tempdb` (temporary scratch space; DBA can create additional temporary dbs), `model` (template used when creating a new database), `sybsystemdb` (used to manage distributed txns); there are several other system dbs that can exist depending on options/features the DBA enables.

Any other databases would fall under the heading of `user` databases.

And yeah, a user db would be similar to a HANA tenant db, though all ASE databases are accessed via the same host:port combo (HANA tenants have their own port if I recall correctly).

Comment: So, one instance can have more than one user database? Like Ms sql

Comment: MSSQL's parent **is** ASE soooo ... MSSQL can have more than one user database just like ASE.:-)